# Adding to email message body after the user selects send | Swift

Tags: swift, email

Currently I have the following function that allows the user to press a button and allow them to compose an email:

```
@IBAction func emailButton(_ sender: Any) {

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
        let device : UIDevice = UIDevice()
        let modelName = device.deviceModel

        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mail.setSubject("Example Subject")
        mail.setToRecipients(["example@example"])
        mail.setMessageBody("<p>Please provide some information below:</p> 
        <br><br><br>", isHTML: true)
        present(mail, animated: true)
    } else {
    }
}
```

I need to add the following info right before the email is sent, so that it is still delivered to the recipient but is not shown to the user for them to tamper with.

Is it possible to add to add to the message body without the user seeing it?

Comment: I see, would you recommend some way I could add that device info into the email? I can't have the user mess with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. Once you call `present`, you no longer have any control over any content of the email.

Just add the extra info to the email before you present the mail composer.

My app has had an "email support" feature for 10 years. At the end of the email I include info like app version, iOS version, etc. I have never had a user mess with that part of the email.

My email body is something like this:

> Blah blah blah. Additional details are as follows:<br>
>   <br>
>   <br>
>   <br>
>   <br>
>   <br>
>   ---------------------------------------<br>
>   Do not modify the information below.<br>
>   ---------------------------------------<br>
>   App Version: xxxx
>   ... and the rest ...

My users have never messed with the information. Of course half or more don't even provide any information related to their question either.

One trick that might help is to make the app info text white or in a hidden `<div>`. But I would avoid hiding it. It makes your app look guilty of sending private, secret data. Make it clear. Don't hide it. Be honest.

---

There is a different solution. Don't use `MFMailComposeViewController`. Provide a way for the user to enter their message. Then package all of the data up and submit it to your web server. The only thing you lose doing this is the user's email address. Obviously this approach is of no use if you need to respond to the user.

Comment: I added one more idea to the answer but as I state in the update, it is best avoided.

Comment: @JonathanMense You could also use an attachment, depending on what exactly you're trying to transmit.